# change cell value on another sheet if checkbox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two sheets, sheet A contains the following

| Date | Name | Email | Status | ID |

Sheet B contains

| Date | Name | Email | Status | ID | CheckBox |

I want to write a function that will check if the checkbox is checked in sheet B and look up the ID value next to checkbox in sheet A and change the Status value in sheet A.

Answer (score 0):

#### change cell value on another sheet if checkbox is checked

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    let id = e.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    let osh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let vs = osh.getDataRange().getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
      if (r[4] == id) {
        osh.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue('whatever you want')
      }
    });
  }
}
```